# Computing variance of an SGD iteration

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization, variance, mathematics

It is known that SGD iteration has huge variance. 
Given the iteration update: 
$$
w^{k+1} := w^k - \underbrace{\alpha \ g_i(w^k)}_{p^k},
$$
where $w$ are model weights and $g_i(w^k)$ is gradient of loss function evaluated for sample $i$. How do I compute variance of each update $p^k$? 
I would like to plot it for each iteration and study its behavior during minimization process.

Answer (score 0):

You could plot a graph of update versus iteration and analyze the variation of each update as the number of iteration increases. Like in [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~spehlmann/cs760/_site//project/2017/05/04/intro.html), where they are comparing the variance of the standard gradient descent algorithm versus its stochastic version.

[image]

Comment: thanks, thats very helpful. I was looking at the paper https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4937-accelerating-stochastic-gradient-descent-using-predictive-variance-reduction.pdf , Figure 2c and I wonder how they computed variance of updates there.  I mean I understand the formula for variance, but do I take as mean full gradient for given iteration? or average gradient over all iterates?

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. I don't know, but I guess reading the whole paper could give you this answer.